# Django suddenly can't load static files anymore

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have a django project for which suddenly (after updating PyCharm) the staticfiles can't be loaded anymore. This is the project structure:

```
├── _quanttool
│   ├── _quanttool
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── asgi.py     
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py         
│   ├── _static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── js
│   │   ├── scss
│   │   └── vendor
│   ├── _templates
│   │   ├── base
│   │   ├── funds_tool
│   │   └── transaction_list
│   ├── funds_tool
.
.
.

│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   └── manage.py
├── venv
├── .gitignore
└── README.md
```

In the settings.py file i have configured:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/_static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '_static'
STATICFILES_LOCATION = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_static')]
```

In the base HTML Template I have set `{% load static %}` and `<link href="{% static 'css/sb-admin-2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

I really don't understand why I suddenly get the errors:
 "GET /_static/css/sb-admin-2.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1682" ...

Any idea why Django can't find the staticfiles anymore?

Best

Comment: do you have DEBUG=False

Comment: No it is set to True, also `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is included in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment out `STATIC_ROOT = '_static'` and add the below code to your settings.py file.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/_static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_static'),)
```

If still not work then run this command on terminal

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you so much. Can you elaborate why STATICFILES_LOCATION suddenly stopped working and had to be replaced by STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: It's a configuration issue of setting we need to configure according to inbuilt setting rules. Default is STATICFILES_DIRS,  not this STATICFILES_LOCATION.
If you are new to Django then I refer you to follow the official documentation of Django
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles ,  https://www.djangoproject.com/